# HashMap that can infer key name with name of value's class

Tags: java, guava

Is there something out there, maybe Guava, that could infer the key name of a HashMap from the either the classname or variable name of the key value? Like:

```
public Class MyBean {
   //basic properties, getters, setters, etc.
}

MyBean myBean = new MyBean();
Map<String, Object> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myHashMap.put(myBean);
System.out.println(myHashMap.get("myBean"));
```

Comment: Note: Map<String, ?> is the same as Map<String, ? extends Object>

Comment: Also note: It doesn't make any sense to create a map with `?` as its value type... wildcards are for when your code is _given_ something it doesn't control the creation of and you want to accept a range of unknown types. You also _can't_ create such an object; the compiler doesn't let you.

Comment: yup, sry, was just writing this from my head (and i edited the question:
Map<String, Object> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

Answer (score 1):

It would be impossible to do from the variable name - because by the time the *value* of the variable has been passed to the `put` method, the variable name is effectively lost. There can be multiple variables referring to the same object, or *no* variable:

```
myHashMap.put(new SomeOtherBean()); // What key would be used?
```

It would be easy to do it by class name, but that would have a pretty limited utility, I suspect.

Comment: in that case, it would be 
myHashMap.get("someOtherBean") -- i think this would be really useful, in most instances, a lot of code just defaults to this anyways-

Comment: @chrismarx: I can't say I've *ever* seen a situation where I'd use this. Normally my HashMaps contain many values of the *same* type.

Comment: i agree that if you're adding things like String, then of course it would be the variable name that you'd want to use (and you've pointed out that that probably isn't possible). but if you're adding bean names, say to a map of parameters, or for creating JSON, then the bean's classname would be useful to use

Comment: @chrismarx: In that case it's really easy to do. You could either derive from HashMap or write a class which *takes* a Map and delegates to it.

Comment: im looking for a more official implementation of this, something in Spring, Guava, another collections library, etc-

Comment: @chrismarx: Well I've never heard of anyone wanting this before, and equally I've never heard of another implementation. For the sake of a few lines of code, why not just do it yourself?